# can I use the IF function in the problem below?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

[image]

How do I use the IF function (or another function) in ce;;s C2-C11 with the condition that if in Cell B5 I have "*" the rezult should be "0" in cell C5 and if in cell B2 I have a number the result in Cell C2 should be equal to the value in Cell C1

How do I use the IF function (or another function) in ce;;s C2-C11 with the condition that if in Cell B5 I have "*" the rezult should be "0" in cell C5 and if in cell B2 I have a number the result in Cell C2 should be equal to the value in Cell C1

Comment: Hi Denis, could you please clarify the logic? I am assuming in C2 you need 0 if B2 is *. Else, you want to repeat the number above (C1). Following the same for C#: 0 if B2 is * and C2 if it is a number. Is this the logic?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:  =IF(NOT(B2="*"),C1,0)